# Why does it take so long until my workers start my big matrix multiplication despite using bigmatrix and sending only the descriptor?

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing, r-bigmemory

I want to implement a parallelized version of the operation `M %*% t(M)`. I have a machine with 100 cores and shared memory/hard drive available, which I want to use as efficiently as possible.

Because my matrix is quite big (20000x15000), I want to avoid splitting the matrix and sending the chunks to the workers directly, because this occurrs serially.

Instead, by using the `bigmemory` package, I can send only the matrix descriptor and the row indices to my workers. This is small data, so each worker should be "briefed" quite quickly. Each worker would then attach the matrix, which is in shared memory, in parallel. Same goes with the output matrix, where each worker writes to in parallel (each to different rows, of course)

The problem is, however, that it still takes quite long for the workers to start working, which leads to the situation that I cannot use all workers, because the first ones are done when the last workers start. Below is a screenshot of htop where you can see the situation.

Also, the duration it takes until the next worker starts gets longer, the bigger the input matrix is. I don't understand this. As you can see below, the function `mult` that I execute in parallel gets an integer vector of 2 (first/last row) and two objects created by `bigmemory::describe`; these objects do not depend on the size of the input matrix. Why does the worker take longer to start for bigger matrices?

## Screenshot of `htop`:

[image: htop output]

## MCVE

`matOuter` definition below. Execute:

```
mkmatrix <- function(n)
   matrix(sample(x = 10, size = n^2, replace = TRUE), nrow = n, ncol = n)
clu <- parallel::makeCluster(100)
n <- 10000 
# n <- 1000  # the workers start faster one after another with a smaller matrix
M <- mkmatrix(n)
p <- matOuter(M, parallel = clu)
stopCluster(clu)
```

Function definition:

```
matOuter <- function(M, parallel = 1){
  if(is.numeric(parallel)){
    # Make a new cluster
    if(parallel == 1) return( M %*% t(M))
    parallel = parallel::makeCluster(parallel)
    on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(parallel))
  } # else use the provided cluster.

  # Get row index ranges for each worker to tackle
  x <- ceiling(seq(1, nrow(M)+1, length.out = min(nrow(M), length(parallel)) + 1))
  idxFrom <- x[-length(x)]
  idxTo <- x[-1] - 1
  idx <- cbind(idxFrom, idxTo)

  bM <- bigmemory::as.big.matrix(M, type = "double") # bigalgebra::%*% needs type double (see bigalgebra:::check_matrix)
  bMOut <- bigmemory::big.matrix(nrow(M), nrow(M), dimnames = rownames(M))

  mult <- function(row, descIn, descOut){
      library(bigalgebra)
      A <- bigmemory::attach.big.matrix(descIn)
      O <- bigmemory::attach.big.matrix(descOut)
      O[row[1]:row[2], ] <- t(bigmemory::as.matrix(A %*% t(A[row[1]:row[2],,drop = FALSE])))
      return(NULL)
  }
  dM <- bigmemory::describe(bM)
  dO <- bigmemory::describe(bMOut)
  # Serial version for debugging.
  #apply(idx, 1, mult, descIn = dM, descOut = dO)
  parallel::parApply(parallel, idx, 1, descIn = dM, descOut = dO, FUN = mult)
  return(bigmemory::as.matrix(bMOut))
}
```

## Session info

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /opt/Bio/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/Bio/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] prAtm_0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17        roxygen2_6.0.1      digest_0.6.15      
 [4] withr_2.1.1         commonmark_1.4      R6_2.2.2           
 [7] magrittr_1.5        bigmemory.sri_0.1.3 rlang_0.1.6        
[10] stringi_1.1.6       testthat_2.0.0      xml2_1.2.0         
[13] bigmemory_4.5.33    devtools_1.13.4     tools_3.4.3        
[16] stringr_1.2.0       parallel_3.4.3      yaml_2.1.16        
[19] compiler_3.4.3      memoise_1.1.0
```

Comment: First question: what do you mean by "I have a cluster with 100 cores available"?. Is it only one computer where you have the data?

Comment: Yes; all cores have access to the same hard drive and memory; question edited.

Comment: Try running `cmd <- "[[ $(uname) = 'Darwin' ]] && sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu_max || lscpu -p | egrep -v '^#' | sort -u -t, -k 2,4 | wc -l"; as.integer(system(cmd, intern = TRUE))`. Try again with the number of cores you get.

Comment: I tried that and got a value of 60. Alas, using `clu <- parallel::makeCluster(60); 
 p <- matOuter(M, parallel = clu)` produced the same behaviour. Do you know for example any possiblity to visualize what is sent to the workers?

Comment: Not really. I've never used more than 12 cores. Can you try with less?

Comment: It also "works" with less, for example 10. However, as `n` must be large, you'll have to cancel it if you don't want to wait forever. But I can also see that each worker starts with a delay compared to the worker before.

Comment: Honestly, I've not the answer to this specific problem. Yet, what I can tell you is that I've already tried to parallelize matrix operations and every time, the simplest and fastest solution was to use an optimized Math library like the MKL.

Comment: @F.Privé The usage of B supplied BLAS/LAPACK instead of MKL or openBLAS jumps out, indeed.